# Double value inserted as 0 after deploying application

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core-mvc

This is my first question so I'll try to be concise.

We are building a website with MVC asp.net and when trying to insert a double value (whitch represents latitude as in coordinates :45,94837|9,32747 for example)
on our machines , in localhost all works as expected. but after deployment on our cloud aws EC2 machine (with IIS webserver) It just inserts zero in the db.

In the insert form we use this kind of input:

```
     <div class="form-group">
            <label class="control-label">Latitudine:</label><br />
            <input type="text" id="impLat" pattern="^-?[0-9]{1,2}([,][0-9]{1,10})?" title="La latitudine puo assumere valori tra -90 e +90 con max 8 cifre significative dopo la virgola. Utilizzare solo la virgola" step="any" class="form-control" asp-for="@Model.imp.ipt_PosizioneLat" />
        </div>
```

So the model of the data is the following:

```
      public Impianto()
     {   ipt_Id = new int();
        ipt_PosizioneLat = new double();
        ipt_PosizioneLong = new double();
        ipt_PotenzaNominale = new int();
        ipt_RagioneSociale = "";
        ipt_Cliente = new int();
        ipt_Torcia = "";
        ipt_Separatore = "";
        ipt_Soffiante = "";
        ipt_Pompa = "";
        ipt_Regione = new int();

    }
    public Impianto(int id,double lat,double lon,int pot,string rag,int 
    clt,string tor,string sep,string sof,string pom,int reg)
    {
        ipt_Id = id;
        ipt_PosizioneLat = lat;
        ipt_PosizioneLong = lon;
        ipt_PotenzaNominale = pot;
        ipt_RagioneSociale = rag;
        ipt_Cliente = clt;
        ipt_Torcia = tor;
        ipt_Separatore = sep;
        ipt_Soffiante = sof;
        ipt_Pompa = pom;
        ipt_Regione = reg;
    }
    public int ipt_Id { get; set; }
    public double ipt_PosizioneLat { get; set; }
    public double ipt_PosizioneLong { get; set; }
    public int ipt_PotenzaNominale { get; set; }
    public string ipt_RagioneSociale { get; set; }
    public int ipt_Cliente { get; set; }
    public string ipt_Torcia { get; set; }
    public string ipt_Separatore { get; set; }
    public string ipt_Soffiante { get; set; }
    public string ipt_Pompa { get; set; }
    public int ipt_Regione { get; set; }
}
```

In our controller we have 2 ActionResults that allow user input in an insert modal and then call a function with the query to insert the data like this:

```
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Operator")]
    [HttpGet]
    public IActionResult InsertImpianto()
    {
        var model = new InsertImpiantoViewModel();
        model.clientidaiqualiscegliere = _data.GetClients();
        model.regionidallequaliscegliere = _data.GetRegions();
        return PartialView(model);
    }
    [Authorize(Roles = "Admin,Operator")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult InsertImpianto(InsertImpiantoViewModel model)
    {
         _data.InsertImpianto(model.imp);
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

The query function is the following:

```
     using (var connection = new SqlConnection(this._connectionString))
        {
            connection.Open();

            connection.Execute(@"USE[tick]
              INSERT INTO [dbo].[Impianto]
                       ([ipt_PosizioneLat]
                       ,[ipt_PosizioneLong]
                       ,[ipt_PotenzaNominale]
                       ,[ipt_RagioneSociale]
                       ,[ipt_Cliente]
                       ,[ipt_Torcia]
                       ,[ipt_Separatore]
                       ,[ipt_Soffiante]
                       ,[ipt_Pompa]
                       ,[ipt_Regione])
                 VALUES
                       (@ipt_PosizioneLat
                       ,@ipt_PosizioneLong
                       ,@ipt_PotenzaNominale
                       ,@ipt_RagioneSociale
                       ,@ipt_Cliente
                       ,@ipt_Torcia
                       ,@ipt_Separatore
                       ,@ipt_Soffiante
                       ,@ipt_Pompa
                       ,@ipt_Regione)", i);
        }
```

-we thought the problem could be related to globalization issues.
-note that we use a pattern in a text input  to insert the double value

Thanks alot for any help we can get and even for thinking about it ^^

Comment: Have you set the culture to anything in Web.config? You could try setting it manually to your culture.

Comment: hi , we use asp.net core and  the globalization command doesn't  work. it's underlined light blue. however  if you have a snippet or suggestion about how to modify the culture it would help alot. (it's our first project  with  asp.net core)

Comment: without re-creation steps no one here can answer this. You need to narrow down your question to make is answerable. We, obviously, don't have access to your AWS or know how it's configured, only you know this.

Comment: Ahh, you should add the asp.net-core tag :) Check out the official documentation on localisation and internationalisation. That should give you a good start.

Comment: You should provide a [mcve]. Also, edit your question title to reflect what you are asking.

Comment: thanks for your comments we're gonna look up the documentation about internationalisation for now.

Comment: Ok all worked out. Thank you all and have a great day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try to set the default culture on startup by using:

```
var cultureInfo = new CultureInfo("it-IT");

CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = cultureInfo;
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = cultureInfo;
```

If you need a more fine-graded management of request culture then you should follow [the samples inside the official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/localization).

Comment: Do you need anything in the dB as well? Have you experienced this insertion of zero's before? Or is this answer based on OPs first comment?

Comment: As I said locally the db doesnt have any problems and neither the insertion of the data.

Comment: @JeremyThompson That was written before the last edit.

Comment: All worked out ^^ thanks alot !! I love StackOverflow and the community :) have a great day !